# Vim Open Resource

Tags: eclipse, vim

When programming in Eclipse I love to use the Open Resource dialog (Ctrl + Shift + R), which opens a simple filter with all the files in the project. My question is: is there something similar for the Vim editor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anything in Eclipse that does fuzzy searching, like command-t in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Command-T plugin does something similar:

https://wincent.com/products/command-t

From the developer's description:

> Files are selected by typing characters that appear in their paths, and are ordered by an algorithm which knows that characters that appear in certain locations (for example, immediately after a path separator) should be given more weight.

Once you find the file you want, you can open it in the current window, a new window, or a new tab.

See this answer on SuperUser for more details and a simple example:

https://superuser.com/questions/159018/flattened-package-browsing-in-vim/160793#160793

Answer (score 0):

Another plugin is [Ctrl-P](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim). It has a similar feature set as command-t.